# Service Worker cache limit?

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

Does anyone know what the limit is with service workers caching content? I've read a size limit of about 50MB (lowest one, but varies).

My problem though, is it appears my service worker's cache is cutting off at 50 files as well (it doesn't reach the size limit, so I can't comment on that part). When I open a cache and count the number of files, it's 50. If it tries to cache more, some get replaced with the newly added files. I can't cache things like I would like to.

Anyone have any tips/ideas? The storage used is 9.2MB for cache storage, and 24.3 for service workers (Total at 9.2MB still). The data limit isn't being reached, just appears to be a file count cap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized this was just Google Chrome only showing 50 files per page, and there's a paging system at the top. There are around 102 files cached right now.
In case anyone else is confused by this as I was.

Answer (score 0):

In our application we can use the [`Quota Management API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageQuota) to programmatically verify the amount of data cached and how much space is left:

```
navigator.storageQuota.queryInfo("temporary")
  .then(function(info) {
     // It gives us the quota in bytes
     console.log(info.quota);

     // It gives us the used data in bytes
     console.log(info.usage);
});
```

[Google Dev Docs](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa#how_much_can_i_store) provide also some explanations about the topic:

[image]